# jquery.balloon.jsにて動的に指定したオブジェクトのバルーンをhideBalloonしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery.balloon.jsを使用し，動的にshowBalloonとhideBalloonを設定したいと思っています．
showBalloonでは，以下のようにバルーン内に閉じるボタンを設定し，それをクリックすることでhideBalloonを呼び出すよう定義しています．

```
function f1(j_obj, text) { // j_objはjqueryオブジェクト
    var id = j_obj.attr('id');
    var btn = '<input type="button" value="閉じる" onclick="f2(' + id + ')"/>';
    j_obj.showBalloon({
        html : true,
        contents : '<div>' + text + btn + '</div>'
    });
}

function f2(obj) {
    $(obj).hideBalloon();
};
```

しかし，showBalloonは正常に動作しますが，hideBolloonが上手く動作せず，閉じるボタンを押してもバルーンが消えません．
jquery.balloon.jsは，作成したバルーン情報を.data('balloon')に格納しているようですが，
どうやらf1()内で格納されたdata属性がf2()内では消えてしまっているようです．
（f1内ではj_obj.data() = {'balloon'}となっていますが，f2内では$(obj).data() = {}となってしまいます．f1のj_objとf2の$(obj)が同一であることは確認しています．)

なぜf2ではdata属性が取得できないのでしょうか．data属性にスコープは無いと思うのですが……．また，閉じるボタンを押した際にhideBalloonするにはどうすればよいでしょうか．

よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDが`div1`の時に出力された要素を確認すると以下のようになっていました。

```
<input type="button" value="閉じる" onclick="f2(div1)"/>
```

`div1`の部分は文字列で渡さなくてはならないでいかのように書く必要があります。

```
var btn = '<input type="button" value="閉じる" onclick="f2(\'' + id + '\')"/>';
```

出力

```
<input type="button" value="閉じる" onclick="f2('div1')"/>
```

また、f2内では`$(obj)`と使用していますが、ここはIDを指定するセレクタを書く必要があるので`$("#" + obj)`のようにします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．私もそう思ったのですが，そうすると`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLSpanElement]`というエラーが出ます．なぜかエレメントとして渡されているようです．`$(obj)`とすることで，jqueryオブジェクト取得できています．

Comment: idの部分が文字列になってないからですね。回答に追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます．エスケープを入れることで文字列にすることができ，$("#" + obj)にてjqueryオブジェクトとして取得することができました．しかし，問題のhideBalloonが動作しない現象が解決できません．f2内で，やはり$("#" + obj).data() = {}となってしまいます．

Comment: 質問にあるコードで動かしていますが、こちらではhideBaloonは動作していますしdata()の取得できています。jquery-3.1.1、jquery.baloon.jsは0.3.0を使用しています。

Comment: いまさらですが、バルーンに表示する閉じるボタンにはonclickを書かずに、jQueryでハンドラを追加するほうがいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

閉じるボタンのタグにonclick属性を書くより、jQueryでハンドラを追加するほうが楽に出来ます。

```js
$(function() {
    $("#baloon").click(function() {
        f1($(this), "hoge");
    });
});
function f1(j_obj, text) { // j_objはjqueryオブジェクト
    var btn = '<input type="button" class="close" value="閉じる"/>';
    j_obj.showBalloon({
        html : true,
        contents : '<div>' + text + btn + '</div>'
    });
    j_obj.data().balloon.on("click", ".close", function() {
     j_obj.hideBalloon();
        console.log(j_obj.data());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
<button id="baloon">test</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます．どうやら別のコードが悪さをしていて上手くいかなかったようです．そちらを修正したら正常に動作しました！ また，わざわざ具体的な修正コードも教えてくださり，ありがとうございました．非常に勉強になりました！